# How to pass data using props from A => B => C in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am quite new to VueJS. I am writing an application wherein I need to pass data from parent to it's child, and then again to it's child. So basically, if A is at the top of the order, my data flow begins from A like this, A => B => C, where C is B's child.

My code looks like this,

**A.vue**

```js
import B from './B.vue';

 export default {
 data(){
  return{
            info:[],

            errors: []
  }
 },
  
  created: function(){
  
    this.accessInformation();
  },

    methods: {
        
        accessInformation: function(){
            this.info.push(response.data.rows[1])
        }
    },

 components: {        
        'b': B,
        
    }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <b :info="info"></b>
  </div>
</template>
```

I am trying to access props and send it this way to C.vue

**B.vue**

```js
import C from './c.vue'

export default{

    props:['info'],

    components:{
        'c': C
    }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <c :info="info"></c>
  </div>
</template>
```

Finally I am trying to access the props data sent from B.vue like this

**C.vue**

```js
export default{

  props:['info']

}
```

Basically, I am trying to access the data sent all the way from A.vue. I am not able to access the data in C.vue. I know I am wrong. Can someone please help me out here. Thanks!

Comment: Should work I think... which errors are you getting?

Comment: @Traxo In C.vue, when I execute, created: function(){ console.log(this.info);}, and check the console, I see undefined

Comment: This example is incomplete.where is `response` coming from?